# package upload on PYPI

Tags: python, pypi

Is there any way to upload the requirement.txt file on PYPI.So that I can install the necessary dependency for this package.
I have uploaded my project but there is no requirements.txt file.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/#connecting-to-the-database

Comment: The problem isn't in the settings file. I tried your settings in my own project and everything went through. The error must be in your views.py file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not upload your requirements.txt on PyPI. Instead, include your requirements in the `install_requires` section in your setup.py.

See [here](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/master/setup.py#L139) the example in the sample setup.py by the Python Packaging Authority.